# Find the common columns between a list of Data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the common columns between a list of Data frames, the way that I started is, I defined x1 that is a lists of list ( for each data frames columns name), then I extract each sub list to a separate list.

I have the output as follows:

```
lst_1=['a1,a2,a3']
```

which has to be as follows, to be able to use set(lst_1) & set(lst_2)& etc :

```
lst_1=["a1","a2","a3"']
```

The code

```
x1=[]
dfs = [list of df]

for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    x1.append([",".join((str(i) for i in df.columns))])

    globals()[f'lst_{i}']= x1[i]
```

Comment: What do you mean "Common columns between a list of data frames"? Are you looking for match purely on column name, or something more complicated like the data in the columns?

Comment: Exactly I want match name of column between many data frames stored in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `reduce` with `set` intersection

```
from functools import reduce

common = reduce(lambda a, b: set(a) & set(b), dfs)
```

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: Check the edit. If you want to be more explicit you can use `reduce(lambda a, b: set(a) & set(b), [df.columns for df in dfs])`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Shubham's answer using `reduce` but expanding to include pulling columns from an arbitrarily sized list of dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd 
from functools import reduce

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b2': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [3,4,5]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b2': [4, 5, 6], 'c2': [3,4,5]})

list_of_dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
cols = [[col for col in df.columns] for df in list_of_dfs]

print(list(reduce(lambda i, j: i & j, (set(x) for x in cols))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `Index`es support set operations without having to convert them to sets, which may be useful if you want to return another `Index`.

```
columns = [df.columns for df in dfs]
print(reduce(lambda a, b: a & b, columns))
```